# cUrl с динамическим proxy, но что бы его получить нужно перейти по ссылке, а без proxy не переходит

Tags: php, curl, proxy

У меня такая задача: есть PHP-скрипт, который с помощью модуля cUrl  переходит по ссылке(нужно только перейти и всё), но без proxy он не переходит. Если указать один proxy, то он некоторое время подействует и не отвечает, это нормально, ибо он открытый, но мне нужно что бы без перебоев. Есть сервис, который возвращает адрес "живого" proxy в формате json, его получим, декодируем и получим адрес proxy, но что бы получить этот адрес, то всё равно нужно переходить по ссылке. Вот такой замкнутый круг.

Answer (score 1):

Подключайтесь к сервису без прокси, получайте прокси, подключайте прокси в CURL и переходите по ссылке.

Если запрос по ссылке дал пустой ответ - значит прокси сдохла, отключайте прокси и получайте от сервиса новый живой прокси и т.д.

Можно сделать 2 экземпляра CURL, один с прокси, другой без и их использовать по алгоритму выше.

Comment: Нет это не выход. У меня cUrl без proxy не подключается и даёт пустой результат.